# Symfony ManyToOne remove the relation without updating the child entity

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-2.7

I have an entity `Serveur` which have a ManyToOne relation with `Responsable`

```
class Serveur implements NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var \MyBundle\Entity\Responsable
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\MyBundle\Entity\Responsable", inversedBy="serveurs", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="serveur_responsable", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     *
     */
    private $responsable;
```

---

```
class Responsable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Uid", type="string", unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    private $uid;
```

When you enter a new Responsable, in my updateAction (serveur), I call a service which look if there's already a Responsable with this uid, and If not I return a new Responsable :

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{


    $entity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Serveur')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Serveur entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {

        $resp = $editForm['responsable']->getData();

        if($resp->getUid()){
            $entity_resp = $this->container->get('app.responsable')->getResp($resp->getUid());
            $entity->setResponsable($entity_resp);
        }
        else{
            $entity->setResponsable(null);
        }
```

Now, when I edit a serveur, if there's no responsable and I enter one, it's working wether the responsable exist or not.

But If I edit a serveur which already have a responsable, and I want to setResponsable to null, it's not working :

> An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE responsable SET Uid = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [null, 192]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'UNIQ_52520D076BD640E6'

It's actually trying to UPDATE the uid of the responsable to null, but that's not what I want, I'd like to keep the responsable in the DB and just remove the relation..

Am I missing something ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used DataTransformer :

```
class RespTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface{

    private $om;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    public function transform($resp)
    {
        if(null === $resp){
            return '';
        }

        return $resp->getUid();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($uid)
    {
        if(!$uid){
            return;
        }

        $resp = $this->om
            ->getRepository('MyBundle:Responsable')
            ->findOneByUid($uid);

        if(null === $resp){
            $resp = new Responsable();
            $resp->setUid($uid);
        }

        return $resp;
    }
```